# facet_wrap: omit unneeded x-entries

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have a plot with `facet_wrap` where some combinations of my x-axis and the faceting variable are not present in the data set.

I would like to omit these completely in the plot but cannot find a way of doing so.

Consider this example:

```
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ>3, trans %in% c("auto(l5)", "manual(m5)"), cty<15) %>% mutate(displ=as.integer(displ), displ_char=case_when(displ==3~"a_three", displ==4~"b_four", displ==5~"c_five", displ==6~"d_six")), 
   aes(x=displ_char, y=cty)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(vars(trans), nrow = 1)
```

This produces the following plot:

[image: plot_output]

Note, however, that e.g. `auto(l5)` has no `displ_char` values of `a_three` (likewise for `manual(m5)` and `d_six`. I would like to remove those. The desired output looks like this (produced with image editing):

[image: desired_output]

This could be achieved by (on-the-fly) data manipulation or plotting options, but only factor levels that are actually present should be plotted on the x-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `scales = "free_x"` argument in `facet_wrap`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg %>% filter(displ>3, trans %in% c("auto(l5)", "manual(m5)"), cty<15) %>% mutate(displ=as.integer(displ), displ_char=case_when(displ==3~"a_three", displ==4~"b_four", displ==5~"c_five", displ==6~"d_six")), 
       aes(x=displ_char, y=cty)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(vars(trans), nrow = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Is there some way to force the width of each x-tick to be the same, instead of equivalent widths of each wrap panel? My actual plot has 1 entry on one panel, and 4 on another, which looks odd.

Comment: @Ivo You can try to use `facet_grid` with the argument `space = "free"`

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Exactly what I wanted! :)